# .NET Core and System.Drawing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to reference *System.Drawing* in a .NET Core console application targeting .NET 4.6, but the assembly is not there.

According to Microsoft, if you use .NET Core, *System.Drawing* is not available. But if you reference the full .NET framework, you should be able to use it.

This is my *project.json* file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

    "dependencies": {

    },

  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
    }
  }
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Did you read your own question in the first place? Your first sentence says __I am trying to reference System.Drawing in a .net core console app targeting net46__, which tells me you don't understand difference between ASP.NET Core and .NET Core. I just explained it for you, to help you avoid confusion in future or to **fix** your question. Because for people reading the question its not clear if you want to run it on .NET Core, .NET framework. It's contradicting, because .NET Core and .NET Framework are mutually exclusive. ASP.NET Core runs on both, but ASP.NET Core is a webstack, not runtime

Comment: @Tseng who mentioned asp.net? You mentioned it man.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I meant the VS template. But I did not mention ASP.NET

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`System.Drawing` is [not a good option with ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing?view=net-6.0#remarks).

If you want graphics manipulation, I suggest to use [ImageSharp](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageSharp) on .NET Core or [ImageProcessor](http://imageprocessor.org/) / [ImageResizer](https://imageresizing.net/) on .NET Framework.

Also, if you really need to use `System.Drawing`, change frameworks in your *project.json* file to `netstandard1.6` and add in dependencies `"NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"`.

Comment: Thanks. Although it is still in Alpha version and cannot find any documentation. Hope that no bugs exist because I will run it in production env. very soon.

Comment: I just realized I also target full .NET Framework in my project and I have a reference to `"NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"`, but how come? .NET Standard is a kind of "contract" exposing some APIs that all Frameworks should implement. `System.Drawing` [is quite empty in .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Drawing.Primitives/src/System/Drawing) for the moment and I've been told on Twitter that even with .NET Standard 2.0 coming soon there will be no System.Drawing implementation similar to what is existing on full .NET Framework. I don't understand

Comment: Unfortunately the image format of imagesharp is very limited, with no webp support at all. Pmuch all libraries that do support webp and others rely on system.drawing.

Comment: I removed the link because the domain has been dropped and now links to spam.

Answer (score 29):

I know this is old, but there is now a port of the library called `System.Drawing.Common`. Try installing that one with NuGet.

To make this possible, there is a metapackage called `Windows Compatibility Pack`. However, this metapackage includes many, many Windows related APIs (distributed as packages).

Source: https://developers.de/2018/01/22/how-to-use-system-drawing-in-net-core/

Comment: Also important to consider: As the name suggest: It's only working on windows. This might or might not be a problem.

Comment: System.Drawing.Common works on Windows, Linux and macOS. On Linux and macOS, you need to install its native dependency, ligdiplus. You can do `apt-get install -y libgdiplus` or `brew install mono-libgdiplus`.

Comment: It will no longer be supported on other platforms in net core 7 just FYI

Comment: Also seems it is not WASM compatible. Does not build if even in a dependecy of a dependency.

Answer (score 27):

Add the NuGet reference `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility`.

Notice: mark "Include prerelease"

Of course, it works only if prerelease packages are OK for you.

Comment: Now that netcore3 is out, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

When you want to use ASP.NET Core on the .NET Full Framework only, you can reference the old class libraries like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Drawing": "4.0.0.0",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replace *System.Drawing* with a multi-platform library called [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp).

*If* you're running on Linux, you can also install [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux), so that you don't have to install the dependencies manually.

Answer (score -2):

For .NET 6 Core:

```
install Aspose.Drawing.Common
```

Comment: That is a bit terse. Can you [elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75188531/edit)? Where does it execute (presumably some kind of command line environment)? Which environment was it tested in (incl. versions)? You could also include references to documentation. (But *** *** *** *** *** *** ***without*** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: At first I didn't understand comments like these n'either, but it's executed in the Terminal (or Developer PowerShell?) in Visual Studio. It's the same as installing it in the NuGet Package Manager.

Comment: Aspose's licensing might not be palatable to many though. It's at least $1197 for 1 developer to develop software that can be used in unlimited locations, $1995 for 10 developer to develop software that can be used in a max of 10 locations, and $5586 for 10 developers to develop software that can be used in unlimited locations. You can't make an SDK without paying a monthly fee. I feel like this answer should address 1. Why you need a third party library now. 2. That this is paid software with licence fees, and no free option even for non-commercial use.