# Bitmap declaration error in VS19 after copying code (c#)

Tags: c#, .net-core, bitmap, console, assembly-references

I made a program that generated images, then I copied the code to a new project, but the Bitmap declaration show's this error message: 
**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1069  The type name 'Bitmap' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Drawing'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.  Bubble_generation   E:\Programok\Bubble_generation\Bubble_generation\Program.cs**
I also tried adding the system.drawing.dll manually, but even that didn't work. Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c5qR.jpg  , and here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace Bubble_generation
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap("input.png");
            int r_mem = 0;
            int g_mem = 0;
            int b_mem = 0;
            Color color_mem;
            for (int w = 0; w < image.Width; w++)
            {
                for (int h = 0; h < image.Height; h++)
                {
                    r_mem = image.GetPixel(w, h).R;
                    g_mem = image.GetPixel(w, h).G;
                    b_mem = image.GetPixel(w, h).B;
                    color_mem = Color.FromArgb(r_mem, r_mem, r_mem);
                    image.SetPixel(w, h, color_mem);
                }
            }
            string time = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH_mm_ss");
            image.Save("output_" + time + ".png");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in console mode, you must add this framework assembly reference in  the `References`section of the project in the solution explorer:

```
System.Drawing
```

[.NET Core and System.Drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892189/net-core-and-system-drawing)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/

Comment: I've added System.Drawing like this: Bubble_generation>Dependencies>Assemblies>System.Drawing, but it doesn't work this way either

Comment: I don't understand what is `Bubble_generation>Dependencies`. Did you use the `Add reference` submenu item of the popup menu of the `References` section that is under the `Properties` in the project tree in the solution explorer?

Comment: Yes, I think: I've right clicked on Dependecies, the I clicked Add Reference, then it was empty, so I've clicked browse, after that I've searched for System.Drawing, then choose the one with .dll extension

Comment: I added links in the answer. You must use the section `Assemblies/Framework` (GAC). Not dll import.

Comment: I don't find /Framework, but here's a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/UJCqypB aybe It helps better understanding the situation

Comment: Ok. What is your Visual Studio version and the target (.NET Framework, .NET Core, .NET Standard...)?

Comment: I use VS2019, and .NET Core 2.1