# How convert Byte[] to Image(jpg, png, etc) in c# Core.net

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-core, .net-core

Now i'm using .net for the conecction with database(sql server 2008), there the images of all product has saved in a attribute type "Image" and in c# get the data in type byte[]. I searched for a answer, but the only solution for this, is this code, but it dont function maybe the type of data is deprecated in the news versions of c#, i dont know.

```
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
using System.IO;

public static Image ImageFromByteArray(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    using (Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true, true))
    {
        return (Image)image.Clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: Q: What exactly is "wrong"?  Q: Do you get an error message?  Q: Can you examine the  bytes in your byte[] input, and compare them to the bytes in your database?  Q: Can you save the bytes to disk, and try a) inspecting the bytes, and/or b) viewing the image?

Comment: The problem is not the type of matrix I am using, the problem is that the data type "Image" does not seem to work, and I have not found another way to do it without using any function of that class.
the mistake that doesn't allow me to use that class is "Image does not contain a definiton for 'FromStream'"

Comment: "Does not work" has never been a sufficient problem description. You need to give us *something* to work with here.

Comment: Sorry Christopher, just i want to know if there are other way to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
```

with

```
using System.Drawing;
```

so that you use the `Image` type from `System.Drawing`.

If the namespace cannot be found, make sure the nuget package [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common) is installed in the project.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892189/net-core-and-system-drawing