# Missing Assembly 'System.Drawing.Common'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

My project was building without issues in .net framework 4.8.1

I tried to switch the framework to .net 4.0

It gave me some errors, so I switched back, now I get the following error:

> Error CS0012  The type 'Bitmap' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

I am looking up how to fix it, but I cannot find any answers

I tried adding `System.Drawing.Common` as a reference, but it is not visible under any of the references.

What does this error mean, and how do I fix these errors?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the framework version of your project is actually 4.8 and not higher, or .Net Core or Mono?

Comment: _Something_ is asking for the .NET 7 version of System.Drawing.Common. Read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core and System.Drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892189/net-core-and-system-drawing)

Comment: Hello, here are three methods I suggest you try one by one. 1. Install System.Drawing.Common using the command line. 2. Feel free to find a nuget package to downgrade, and then upgrade 3. Uninstall the solution, and then load it again. See if it works.